# Loop base64_decode

Tags: php, base64, preg-match

Hola Tengo Un un string que fue pasado por base64_encode varias veces, quisiera arma un descodificador inteligente que use el base64_decode hasta que salga la URL oculta. Es decir repetir tantas veces sea necesario aplicar el base64_decode hasta que salga la URL.

Esta data fue pasada 4 Veces por base64_encode. Y quiero reversarla. Y no se como hacer el LOOP.

```
$data_encode='V1ZWb1UwMUhUa2xVVkZwTlpWUnNjMWw2VGtOaFIwNTBWbGhXYTFJelRqSlphMlJ6VFd4d1ZFOVVRbXRpVmxZMFZFY3dkMlZ0VWxWYWVUbHJVbnBzZVZkc1l6QlBWbXh4VVd4c2FHRjZiSEJXYTFKelZFZEtjV0ZJVW14V1IyaGFWa1ZOZUdGc1pFaGxSbEpyWlZad2MxcFZhRU5qUjA1MFZtNXdVVlpGVlhsVVZWSk9UVEExUlZWVVVrOVNSbFU1'
    
    $result=[];
    $http_fil='/((?:https?|http?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]|\.\s|$))/';
    
        if(!preg_match($http_fil,$data_encode, $matches)){;                                     
            $result[] = base64_decode($matches[1]);
        }
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas o sabes que es una "url oculta"? ¿Qué características tiene ese string para saberlo?

Comment: Si te fijas en el Regex estoy verificando por default que tenga una url . De por sí mi fuente de información, Se de antemano que siempre será una una URL.

Comment: Sí, lo sé. Pero, ¿qué estructura tiene esa url o cómo sabes que es una url? ¿Solo lo sabes porque empieza con http o cómo lo sabes?

Comment: Esa que puse te debera resultar asi: https://espare.tk/live/antena3.m3u8?token=q_2V9O86JREnWQ5EX0K2fg&expires=1603773478